# JXLS grouping with xml markup

Tags: java, xml, jxls

Is `groupBy` supported via xml configuration for JXLS 2.x?

Reason being I have a very basic grouping example that works with excel comments but simply refuses to work when I use the same configuration via xml markup. Output excel is grouped, but there is no data under each group.

I could not find any working examples online as well so either something is wrong with my syntax (see below) or `groupBy` is NOT supported in JXLS 2.x via xml markup.

**excel comments** (this works!)

[image]

**detail_config.xml xml configuration** (does not work!)

```
<xls>
    <area ref="Template!A1:D4">
        <each items="clockinouts" groupBy="employeeName" groupOrder="asc" ref="Template!A1:D3">
            <area ref="Template!A1:D3">
                <each items="_group.items" var="clockinout" ref="Template!A2:D2">
                    <area ref="Template!A2:D2"/>
                </each>
            </area>
        </each>
    </area>
</xls>
```

**Java code to load xml configuration**

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    List<ClockInOut> clockInOuts;

    clockInOuts = loadCSV();
    InputStream is = GroupingDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("detail_template.xlsx");

    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("target/detail.xlsx")) {
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.createTransformer(is, os);
        try (InputStream configInputStream = GroupingDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("detail_config.xml")) {
            AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XmlAreaBuilder(configInputStream, transformer);
            List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
            Area xlsArea = xlsAreaList.get(0);
            Context context = new Context();
            context.putVar("clockinouts", clockInOuts);
            xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Template!A1"), context);
            transformer.write();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/src/master/jxls/src/main/java/org/jxls/builder/xml/EachAction.java), it looks like XML markup only supports `item`, `var`, `dir`, and `ref` attributes, hence the above behavior is expected. Raised an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/196/groupby-support-for-xml-markup) in the JXLS repository, so hopefully, this will get fixed in a future version.

Right now Excel markup seems to be the way forward.